# How to group multi conditions in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a trouble group multi conditions on laravel version 8

```
$filters['house_year'] = ["0_5","10_20"]
$this->model = ...// Properties model    

$this->model = $this->model->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
   foreach ($filters['house_year'] as $filter) {
      switch ($filter) {
         case "0_5":
            $query = $query->where('house_year', '>=', 0);
            $query = $query->where('house_year', '<', 5);
         break;
         
         case "5_10":
            $query = $query->where('house_year', '>=', 5);
            $query = $query->where('house_year', '<', 10);
         break;

         case "10_20":
            $query = $query->where('house_year', '>=', 10);
            $query = $query->where('house_year', '<', 20);
         break;
          
         default:
            $query = $query->where('house_year', '>=', 20);
         break;
      }
   }
   return $query;
});
$this->model = $this->model->where('status', 1);
...
```

How to fix it for this result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM properties 
WHERE ((house_year >= 0 AND house_year < 5) OR (house_year >= 10 AND house_year < 20)) 
AND status = 1
```

Comment: you should add one more subquery. `$query->where(function($q) use ($filters){` something like this and then loop it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query->orWhere(function($q){
      $query = $query->where('house_year', '>=', 0);
      $query = $query->where('house_year', '<', 5);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$data = Property::where('status', 1)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        return $query
            ->whereBetween('house_year', [0, 5])
            ->orWhereBetween('house_year', [10, 20]);
    })
    ->get();
```

Alternatively, if it would include the last positions (AFAIK it wouldn't), you can use kind of this:

```
$data = Property::where('status', 1)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        return $query
            ->where([
                ['house_year', '>=', 0],
                ['house_year', '<', 5],
            ])
            ->orWhereBetween([
                ['house_year', '>=', 10],
                ['house_year', '<', 20],
            ]);
    })
    ->get();
```

**Note**: for this example i've used "Property" model, so you can edit that as for your code requirements.

Comment: from your ideas, I've find solution

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
$this->model = $this->model->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
   foreach ($filters['house_year'] as $k => $filter) {
      switch ($filter) {
         // ...
         case "5_10":
            if($k == 0) {
               $query = $query->whereBetween('house_year', '>=', [5, 10]);
            } else {
               $query = $query->orWhereBetween('house_year', '>=', [5, 10]);
            }
         break;
         // ...
      }
   }
   return $query;
});
```